# Playing periodic sound accurately on Android

Tags: android, multithreading, loops, audio

I'm trying to write an Android app that will serve as, among other things, a metronome. This requires the ability to play back various sounds with accurate timing periodically, but for now I'm working on just getting one to work. An error of more than 2-3ms would easily be detected by a trained listener. Here is my playback thread:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // stuff
    int minBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    mAudioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
}

public void startThread(View view){
    mThread = new Thread (new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
            Log.d(TAG, "Starting met at tempo: " + mTempo + " Interval: " + (60000 / mTempo) );

            android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);

            InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.chirp);
            byte [] output = getBytesFromStream(in);

            Log.d(TAG, "Output length: " + output.length);

            mAudioTrack.play();
            while (mRunning) {
                mAudioTrack.write(output, 0, output.length);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(60000 / mTempo);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }

            mAudioTrack.release();
        }
    });

    mThread.start();
}
```

R.raw.chirp is a sinewave generated in Audacity. 1000hz sampled at 44100hz for 100ms, so it should be about 4410 samples. Testing this on a Nexus 4, with the tempo set to 200bpm (i.e. the chirp should play every 300ms) the sound appeared to be good, but for good measure I recorded the output into Audacity through line-in. I noticed two oddities:

1) The chirp appeared to be playing in periods of somwhere between 298-299 ms. This was for the most part consistent, but that 1-2ms changes the tempo to 201bpm, which is enough to knock it out of sync with a reference metronome.

2) The second oddity was not consistently repeatable, but after a seemingly random number of chirps there would be a single chirp delayed by a full 20ms.

The second issue I could conceivably explain away; perhaps a threading/priority issue? However, the first issue baffles me. I would think if anything the chirps should come late, rather than early. I believe these issues are related, and I also am starting to think I don't properly understand what is happening and am doing something very basic wrong (this is my first time working with audio code of any sort.)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to presently using a poor timing source, there's the larger problem that Android offers only comparably loose and substantially variable coupling between the time when playback is requested and when it actually happens.

To work around that, play sound continuously - mostly silence - and mix in your desired clicks at the desired time.  Instead of using any of the ordinary software-accessible system clocks to determine time, use the count of previously written samples, so that your timing will have a fixed relationship to the digital-to-analog-converter sampling clock.

Comment: Thanks. This is ultimately what I thought I was going to have to do, but I wanted to see what would happen doing it this way. I figured it wouldn't work, but it's the particular manner in which it does not work that confuses me. I assumed there would be a delay of some sort between writing the data and hearing it, by the asynchronous nature of the function. This doesn't explain why most of the beats were coming out consistently earlier than expected, though.

Answer (score 0):

So you're depending on sleep being accurate.  It isn't.  It isn't designed to be.  It will sleep for *at least* that time, but may sleep for more.  The OS will not do a task switch back to that thread as soon as the sleep is up, but as soon as it becomes the top priority thread in its scheduling queue.  You need a far more reliable way of waiting-  something based on an RTC.

An alarm based on the RTC alarm type *might* do it.  I'm not sure if it actually is an RTC interrupt that will send you an immediate alarm, or if its just the relative clock it uses.

Comment: The second sentence of your reply is what I expected to happen; however, the behavior being exhibited is that the thread was sleeping for less than the requested amount of time.

Comment: It could just be that the handoff between your thread and the thread doing audio playing happens quicker sometimes than others, resulting in a sped up sound.